# Why is the first space lost in the ouput from this very basic AspNetCore program

Tags: asp.net-core

I was following along with Scott and Naggaga on the "Introduction to ASP.NET Core with VS 2017" and got to the very first web page. And the html in the response is missing the first space. So I get "HelloBrave New World!".

I cannot think why this is happening - there is only 45 lines in the whole thing...

```
supermva.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace supermva
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
Startup.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace supermva
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.Run(context =>
            {
                return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello Brave New World!");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, of course, nothing is wrong with the program. (Stupid question)

If I use Firefox or Chrome, the text is shown fine.

Only with Edge does the first space disappear. Because I use LastPass in Edge and LastPass did the mangling.